# Are Hiera settings inherited when including a class?

Tags: inheritance, puppet, hiera

I have Puppet class Foo with an associated Foo.yaml file containing Hiera settings. I need to create a descendant class (Bar) that includes all settings and code from Foo plus some additional Hiera settings.

Is in enough to use "include Foo" in the Bar class definition and create Bar.yaml with extra settings? Or should I additionally copy Foo.yaml to Bar.yaml and add new settings to Bar.yaml? The former approach is preferable but I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: Given how theoretical the question is, I cannot be certain beyond saying it "should" work to `require foo` in this case (would be preferred over `include` in this situation). This also sounds like a far from best practices architecture though.

Comment: What's a "descendant" class?  If I thought you were talking about class inheritance then I'd warn you off in no uncertain terms, but if that were what you had in mind then you wouldn't (at least shouldn't) be looking to `include` one class in the other.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard, this is about adding Windows Defender exclusions on a subset of WIn2016 servers with a complex Puppet class already applied. All other settings and installed components should be identical on all the servers. However, as this is not the most common scenario, for clarity's sake I decided to omit practical details and make this a theoretical question.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I'm more used to classic object programming terms. Yes, it's about class inheritance. Why shouldn't I include an existing class into a new one?

Comment: @Evgeny, using `include`, `require`, or `contain` to include one class in another is perfectly fine.  It is *not* inheritance.  Puppet has a separate and rather idiosyncratic sense of class inheritance, for which only one good use has ever been discovered.  Moreover, Puppet classes are not "classes" in the sense that the term is used in C++ or Java programming.  They would best be described as (singleton) *objects* in that terminology.

Comment: You can think of it this way: in Puppet, the correct choice between inheritance and composition is always composition.

Comment: Moreover, if you think in terms of composition then the answer to what I think you are asking will become clearer: each class draws on its own set of Hiera keys for class parameter defaults, regardless of the scope(s) in which its declaration appears.  `Foo` is still `Foo`, and gets its own parameters, whether it is declared by a node block or by `Bar`, or both.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to do a `require` or `include` to include all resources from another class (use `require` if you want to ensure an order). But with this, you won't be able to access the hiera settings from the other class. To do so I recommend a hiera lookup in class Bar like

```
class Bar (
  $param1 = lookup("Foo::param1")
) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: A class can access the class parameters of any other class that has been declared as class variables of that other class.  In particular, it can do so for the parameters of classes that it itself has (already) declared.  The `lookup()` function is not needed in such cases. The main caveat here is that any hard-coded default values of a class's own parameters are evaluated before their class has an opportunity to declare any other classes.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I need the Bar class to include all Hiera settings from the parent Foo class except one parameter section redefined in Bar.yaml. The Bar class itself won't contain any code besides "include Foo". All settings should be managed on the Hiera level. Of course, the simplest way would be to just copy Foo.yaml to Bar.yaml and correct the needed section but it'd make the code less manageable and prone to future errors. In classic object-oriented languages, it's be pretty easy. Creating a descendant class that inherits all parent settings and modifying the needed variables, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I've performed a practical experiments with Puppet classes. Unfortunately, seems Hiera doesn't import settings associated with included roles. It imports settings only from the file associated with the current role.

So unless you want to add new settings on the per-server basis, there is only one resolution: copying the content of the source Hiera file into a new file and adding required settings there. After that you'll have to manually sync all new settings in both the parent and descending role settings in Hiera.

I wonder why Puppet creators decided to invent a bicycle and develop an imitation of object-oriented style from scratch instead of adopting well-known and proved approaches...